# How to fix TS2345: Argument of type 'A | B' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A'

Tags: typescript

I got an error that I can't pass an argument type of A to a function which can take A | B

```
type A = {a: number, c: number}
type B = {a: number, b: number}

function ab(param: A | B) {}

const a: A = {a: number}
ab(a)
```

But sometimes in function `ab` I can pass const type of `B`

Comment: I see no error [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnKAXwG4AoUSKAIQWTU10JIqgNfyNMqpUAZjiwBjYAEsA9ljQEAFGFTFUeTHAA+DAJTIygsbIDOwFrCYoMUAIwAmAMzlqqRah0UgA)

Comment: @wonderflame [fix](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnAbigGNNdCSoBfUgKFEigCEFk1r8iyoBXrWINmTAGY4sFYAEsA9ljQEAFGFTFUeTHAA+HAJTJ6TJhSUBnYD1hcUGKAEYATAGYxTVGtSHSQA) pls check

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Suddenly your type `A` has two properties, yet you pass one (assuming `number` is supposed to be an actual number).

Comment: There is `c: number` in the `A`, which is missing in the variable. [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnAbigGNNdCSoBfUgKFEigCEFk1r8iyoBXrWINmTAGY4sFYAEsA9ljQEAFGFTFUeTHAA+HAJTJ6TJhSUBnYD1hcUGKAEYATAGYANJUyuxTVGqohqRAA)

Comment: It's `Property 'c' is missing in type '{ a: number; }' but required in type 'A'.(2741)
` which is not the one you @WhatisLove told. Make a proper example.